# When I include the html in config it does not work

Tags: sencha-touch-2.3

I am bit confused here, look at the code below:

```
var arrReqTplTest=["........................."];
var finalStudent=[];
finalStudent.push({
title: “Student Table”,
                collapsed: true,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'component',
                        itemId: 'StudentTablViewID-' + i,
                        html: arrReqTplTest

                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        itemId: 'StudentTable-' + i,
                        height: 200,
                        store: ‘studentDetailStore’,
                        //itemHeight: 70,
                        scrollable: false,           
                        itemSelector: 'div.wrap-requirements-' + i
                    }
                ]
            });
        }

        view.add(finalStudent);
})
}
});
```

This works fine but now look at the code below which does not work:

```
 var arrReqTplTest=["........................."];
    var finalStudent=[];
    finalStudent.push({
    title: “Student Table”,
                    collapsed: true,
                    layout: 'fit',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'component',
                            itemId: 'StudentTablViewID-' + i,
                            config:{
                                    html:arrReqTplTest
                                }

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'dataview',
                            itemId: 'StudentTable-' + i,
                            height: 200,
                            store: ‘studentDetailStore’,
                            //itemHeight: 70,
                            scrollable: false,           
                            itemSelector: 'div.wrap-requirements-' + i
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }

            view.add(finalStudent);
    })
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

its because **"html"** is part of component's config.
you are doing it right with the first code:

```
html: thisIsYourVariableWithHtml //you can store the html value inside a variable or directly paste the value as string
```

But i will suggest to add:

```
styleHtmlContent: true,
```

to make sure that component really render the html value as html.

now in your second code you write:

```
config: {
    html: thisIsYourVariableWithHtml
}
```

you are defining custom config variable (dunno what other people call it, but this is my term when defining a property inside component's config object) in this case a object called config that have value "html" and by default sencha's component will not know what to do with this as it is your custom config variable.

Comment: But Sencha's component recognizes html as a config option.

Comment: well if you check by getMyComponent.getConfig().getHtml() yes it return the html value, (that is why i refer it as custom config variable)

but it when it comes to running time and rendering the item on viewport sencha will refer to each of default config inside the "{}" such as: xtype, itemId and etc

I've also checked the default config list of component specificly on the documentation and "config" does not appear http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component.